# Ignore n=1 subgroups when using t.test comparisons in R

Tags: r, error-handling, statistics

I wrote a Shiny app that calculates `t.test`s between data subsets based on user input and selected `data.frame`. The input will be variable, so I'm trying to come up with a code that doesn't fail when the comparisons involve `n=1` observations. In other words, I want to calculate `t.test`s and produce results but simply ignore the n=1 subgroups that might arise when the user selects a variable. I tried suppressing errors with `tryCatch` but my approach prevented code evaluation altogether.

A reprex is below for what I'm trying to do. I'm using `ggpubr` for calculating stats and subsequent plotting, but the failure happens at the `t.test` step. Thanks!

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

df1 <- data.frame( y = rnorm(30), 
                  x = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 10),
                  grp = c(rep("grp1", 14),  rep("grp2", 14), rep("grp3", 2)))
head(df1)
#>             y x  grp
#> 1 -0.13492634 a grp1
#> 2 -0.61828715 b grp1
#> 3 -0.63773980 c grp1
#> 4 -0.37607819 a grp1
#> 5 -1.38494920 b grp1
#> 6 -0.02036611 c grp1



compare_means(y~x, data = df1, method = "t.test")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 8
#>   .y.   group1 group2      p p.adj p.format p.signif method
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr> 
#> 1 y     a      b      0.0241 0.072 0.024    *        T-test
#> 2 y     a      c      0.319  0.32  0.319    ns       T-test
#> 3 y     b      c      0.0934 0.19  0.093    ns       T-test

compare_means(y~x, data = df1, method="t.test", group.by = "grp")
#> Error in t.test.default(xi, xj, paired = paired, alternative = alternative, : not enough 'x' observations





# Data frame that will not fail to demonstrate what I want at the end
df2 <- data.frame( y = rnorm(30), 
                   x = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 10),
                   grp = c(rep(c("grp1", "grp2", "grp3"), each=10)))
head(df2)
#>            y x  grp
#> 1  0.6382919 a grp1
#> 2 -0.2909966 b grp1
#> 3  0.8555486 c grp1
#> 4 -1.3737311 a grp1
#> 5 -0.8560113 b grp1
#> 6 -1.2295995 c grp1

# I want an output like this with NAs where computation isn't possible due to n=1
compare_means(y~x, data = df2, method="t.test", group.by = "grp")
#> # A tibble: 9 x 9
#>   grp   .y.   group1 group2      p p.adj p.format p.signif method
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr> 
#> 1 grp1  y     a      b      0.635   1    0.635    ns       T-test
#> 2 grp1  y     a      c      0.607   1    0.607    ns       T-test
#> 3 grp1  y     b      c      0.375   1    0.375    ns       T-test
#> 4 grp2  y     a      b      0.984   1    0.984    ns       T-test
#> 5 grp2  y     a      c      0.719   1    0.719    ns       T-test
#> 6 grp2  y     b      c      0.371   1    0.371    ns       T-test
#> 7 grp3  y     a      b      0.542   1    0.542    ns       T-test
#> 8 grp3  y     a      c      0.0853  0.77 0.085    ns       T-test
#> 9 grp3  y     b      c      0.178   1    0.178    ns       T-test
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using tryCatch, just subset the dataset and use

```
compare_means(y~x, data = subset(df1,ave(y,grp,x,FUN=length)>1), method="t.test", group.by = "grp")
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  grp   .y.   group1 group2      p p.adj p.format p.signif method
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr> 
1 grp1  y     a      b      0.805   1    0.805    ns       T-test
2 grp1  y     a      c      0.686   1    0.686    ns       T-test
3 grp1  y     b      c      0.817   1    0.817    ns       T-test
4 grp2  y     a      b      0.568   1    0.568    ns       T-test
5 grp2  y     a      c      0.153   0.77 0.153    ns       T-test
6 grp2  y     b      c      0.0215  0.13 0.021    *        T-test
```

Comment: Very good! Any suggestions on how I can use `ave` with strings? i.e. I want to pass the column names as characters (coming from user input such as `input$selected_text`)

Comment: I just figured out. Wrapping the strings with `get()` seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Atakan ensure that when you use get, you specify the environment to be `df1` This will avoid many issues. Although you need to use `substitute` rather than `get`

Comment: Could you edit your answer with the use of `substitute` when you get a chance? I think people who might find this post for Shiny applications (like myself) would appreciate it.